# Query contacts with emails, phone numbers and name efficiently

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to query all the contacts list on the device with their name, emails and phone numbers.

Everything works well. However, it takes about 5-8 seconds to fetch all the data (for about 1000 contacts).

As far as I understand, getting phone numbers and emails, each requires a separate query, and probably this is what makes the whole operation take so long.

Is there any way to query both name, numbers and emails in one query request?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,

        };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactsCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    if (contactsCursor == null)
        return;

    while (contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
        ArrayList<String> numbers = getPhoneNumbers(id, contentResolver);
        ArrayList<String> emails = getEmailAddress(id, contentResolver);

        contacts.add(new Contact(name, emails, numbers, id));
    }

    Log.d("", "" +contacts.size());

    contactsCursor.close();
}

private ArrayList<String> getPhoneNumbers(String id, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursorPhone = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{id},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone == null)
        return phoneNumbers;

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        phoneNumbers.add(cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();
    return phoneNumbers;
}

private ArrayList<String> getEmailAddress(String id, ContentResolver contentResolver){
    ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursorEmail = contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{id}, null);

    if(cursorEmail == null)
        return emails;

    while (cursorEmail.moveToNext()){
        emails.add(cursorEmail.getString(cursorEmail.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
    }

    cursorEmail.close();
    return emails;
}
```

}